# Are there other compounds with 分 where it is read as いた as in 大分県?

Tags: kanji, etymology, readings

Not sure if 分 is *ita* or *ta* in 大分県, but anyway, kind of hard to find anything in the dictionary so if anyone knows a compound with that reading off the top of their head it would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I searched the freely available [WWWJDIC](http://nihongo.monash.edu/wwwjdicinf.html) and [ENAMDICT](https://www.edrdg.org/enamdict/enamdict_doc.html) databases for Japanese words and proper/place names, respectively, and no other instances of 分【いた】 are listed in these dictionaries. (These files are quite extensive, containing for instance names of companies or subway stations.)

But more can be said about 分【いた】 by looking at the [etymology](https://kanjibunka.com/kanji-faq/old-faq/q0299/) of 大分【おおいた】, where いた appears to be a sound change from きだ・きた (き → い is a common sound change) and きだ・きた is thought to refer to 段 = きざ・きだ・きた which could refer to the (terraced or extensive) rice paddies around ­Ōita City.

(By the way, there is one other word 段階 = きだはし・きざはし where this reading is also seen, but there are no further instances of 分 or 段 being read as きざ・きだ・きた・いた...)

Comment: FWIW, the [Nihon Jiten etymology entry](http://www.nihonjiten.com/data/249430.html) includes a couple additional theories, including [碩]{おおき}[田]{た} (per [Emperor Keikō](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emperor_Keik%C5%8D), probably apocryphal), and [多]{おお}き[田]{た}.  That said, the おほいた reading has apparently been around since at least the [_Wamyō Ruijushō_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wamy%C5%8D_Ruijush%C5%8D) of 938 CE, which might be too early for the き→い variety of sound shift?

Comment: KKS 440 by Ki no Tomonori (9 cent.) has あきちかう for あきちかく, so apparently the change could be much earlier than what was allowed in texts makes think.